Flutter Location Web hasPermission() throwing TypeError
This method per the documentation seems to work perfectly on iOS and Android but on Web I'm getting a random type error within the package.
Here's my code:
_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      StackTrace.current
          .printWithInfo('No User Location Available: Services Not Enabled!');
      streamController.add(_initialFocusLocation);
      return;
    }
  }

  // try {
  _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied ||
      _permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.deniedForever) {
    _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted ||
        _permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.grantedLimited) {
      StackTrace.current
          .printWithInfo('No User Location Available: Permission Not Granted!');
      streamController.add(_initialFocusLocation);
      return;
    }
  }

The error is thrown at location.hasPermission()
TypeError: Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': Failed to read the 'name' property from 'PermissionDescriptor': Required member is undefined.
packages/location_web/location_web.dart 60:15                               hasPermission

Does anyone have this working on the web?
Packages and versions:
location: 6.0.2
flutter: 3.22.2
dart: 3.4.3

For the web version try the following:
Instead of using: _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
use: _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
